# Glutin on Rust: How do I passively track my mouse movement and position?

Tags: rust, glut

I want to track my cursor position as I work through my day to generate an artistic heat-map later.

To aggregate the data, I've pulled in `glutin` at version `0.29.1` and setup my loop with event matchers that tell me when I move my mouse and where.

The problem I have is that I want this aggregation to continue to work when I don't have the window focused. In the past, with other frameworks, I've been able to get around this kind of limitation by setting a maximized transparent window to always sit on top of all windows, but this hasn't worked for me.

How do I passively track my mouse movement and position with glutin (or another framework, preferably cross-platform so I don't have to dig into lower level apis with more obscure documentation)?

```rust
let event_loop = EventLoop::new();
let _window = WindowBuilder::new()
    .with_decorations(false)
    .with_maximized(true)
    .with_always_on_top(true)
    .with_transparent(true)
    .build(&event_loop);

event_loop.run(move |event, _, _control_flow| match event {
    Event::WindowEvent { event, .. } => match event {
        WindowEvent::CursorMoved {
            device_id,
            position,
            modifiers: _,
        } => {
            println!("{:?} {:?}", device_id, position);
        }
        WindowEvent::Focused(is_focused) => {
            println!("focused::{}", is_focused);
        }
        _ => {}
    },
    Event::DeviceEvent { device_id, event } => match event {
        DeviceEvent::MouseMotion { delta } => {
            println!("{:?} {:?}", device_id, delta);
        }
        _ => {}
    },
    _ => {}
});
```

Comment: Just a general remark: Reading keyboard/mouse input from a non-active window is a slippery slope to getting kicked by a virus scanner. That's a typical behavior of a keylogger.

Comment: @Finomnis, understood. I've built actual corporate monitored non-nefarious keyloggers in the past (working on a DLP product to prevent intelectual-property exfiltration) however they were geared specifically to tag into the Windows API with arcane and unfriendly frameworks and here I want to just monitor my mouse with something light-weight that gets me better acquainted with video-game development and the rust language.

Comment: I might be wrong, but my initial impression is that something like that will have to be necessary. No normal window manager will allow you global access to the mouse, you might have to go through low level driver things for that. Or other abstraction layers, similar to what game engines do. Although most games I know stop working when they loose focus, so I'm not sure about that one.

Comment: I don't believe there is any way to set up a global event listener for mouse movement. You'd likely have to create one yourself that essentially polls the mouse location via platform-specific APIs at regular intervals. There are already some crates that at least wrap the APIs for you so it is as simple as calling a `location()` method.

Comment: @Finomnis, you're half-right. The product I worked on was installed as a kernel driver so it operated outside the user's ability to interfere with it's operation. I'd just hoped that I could use `glutin` as the tool for educational purposes.

Comment: @Herohtar, I think you're right. I'm forcing a solution since my agenda is to learn game-development. I'll save that for the actual heat-map generation. That'll be a better opportunity to learn something relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to hammer a square-peg into a round hole by forcing my usage of `glutin` to learn more along the lines of game-development. This is made trivial by using a more appropriate tool.

```ini
[dependencies]
device_query = "1.1.1"
```

```rust
use device_query::{DeviceState, DeviceEvents};

fn main() {
    let device_state = DeviceState::new();
    loop {
        let mouse_state = device_state.get_mouse();
        println!("{:?}", mouse_state.coords);
    }
}
```

[Edit] or as recommended in the comments with a less resource intense callback, and an additional dependency on `ctrlc = "3.2.3"` to hold the application open indefinitely.

```rust
use device_query::{DeviceState, DeviceEvents};
use std::sync::mpsc::channel;
use ctrlc;

fn main() {
    let device_state = DeviceState::new();
    let _guard = device_state.on_mouse_move(|position| {
        println!("{:?}", position);
    });

    let (tx, rx) = channel();
    ctrlc::set_handler(move || tx.send(()).expect("Could not send signal on channel."))
        .expect("Error setting Ctrl-C handler");
    rx.recv().expect("Could not receive from channel.");
}
```

Comment: I'd go with the more resource-friendly and less error-prone callback based method (also in the same crate)